# Connection issue with distributed marketing cloud and Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, distributed-marketing

We have installed the Distributed marketing cloud manage package inside salesforce org and assigned necessary permission set to the user.

Now from the distributed marketing Admin tab, We have to create a new business unit to connect with the marketing cloud business unit but we are getting below error.

Remote_Error: The remote service returned an error.

Comment: Hello Ravikant, did you solve this issue?

Comment: yes, I have resolved the issue.